# How to compare the values in 2 columns of a dataframe

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, numpy, dataframe

I have the following dataframe:

```
    y   proba   y_pred
0   1.0 0.637387    1
1   1.0 0.635165    1
2   1.0 0.766586    1
3   1.0 0.724564    1
4   1.0 0.889199    1
..
..
```

I want to compare `y` and `y_pred` in order to compute tp=(y=1, y_pred=1), fp=(y=0, y_pred=1), fn=(y=1, y_pred=0), and tn=(y=0, y_pred=0). Here what I tried:

```
tp = 0
fp = 0
fn = 0
tn = 0
if data1['y'] == 1 and data1['y_pred'] == 1:
    tp+= 1
elif data1['y'] == 0 and data1['y_pred'] == 1:
    fp+= 1
elif data1['y'] == 1 and data1['y_pred'] == 0:
    fn+= 1
elif data1['y'] == 0 and data1['y_pred'] == 0:
    tn+= 1
```

But this code throws an error:

> ValueError: The truth value of a Series is ambiguous. Use a.empty, a.bool(), a.item(), a.any() or a.all().

Comment: It's actually a data frame of 3 columns: y,   probe,  y_pred

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can count the number of rows using `len` function, like this:

```
tp = len(data1[data1['y'].eq(1) & data1['y_pred'].eq(1)])
fp = len(data1[data1['y'].eq(0) & data1['y_pred'].eq(1)])
fn = len(data1[data1['y'].eq(1) & data1['y_pred'].eq(0)])
tn = len(data1[data1['y'].eq(0) & data1['y_pred'].eq(0)])
```

No need for loops.

Answer (score 1):

Dont repeat code, here not necessary - only get counts by [`GroupBy.size`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.core.groupby.GroupBy.size.html) and select values in `MultiIndex`:

```
d = {'y': [0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 1.0, 0.0, 0.0, 1.0, 1.0], 
     'proba': [0.637387, 0.635165, 0.766586, 0.637387, 
               0.635165, 0.766586, 0.724564, 0.889199],
     'y_pred': [1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 1]}
df = pd.DataFrame(d)
print (df)
     y     proba  y_pred
0  0.0  0.637387       1
1  0.0  0.635165       1
2  0.0  0.766586       0
3  1.0  0.637387       1
4  0.0  0.635165       1
5  0.0  0.766586       0
6  1.0  0.724564       0
7  1.0  0.889199       1
```

---

```
df1 = df.groupby(['y','y_pred']).size()
print (df1)
y    y_pred
0.0  0         2
     1         3
1.0  0         1
     1         2

tp = df1.loc[(1, 1)]
print (tp)
2
fp = df1.loc[(0, 1)]
print (fp)
3

fn = df1.loc[(1, 0)]
print (fn)
1
tn = df1.loc[(0, 0)]
p2rint (tn)
```

Comment: @ManojKashyap - do you change `df` to `df1` ?

Comment: @ManojKashyap - looks like using `df.loc[(1, 1)]` instead `df1.loc[(1, 1)]`, `df` instead `df1`, answer was edited.